# How can I make rspec-puppet's coverage report say I have tested my moule's base class?

Tags: code-coverage, puppet

I get the following [when testing my module](https://travis-ci.org/genebean/genebean-nxlog/jobs/65832490) and am not sure what test it thinks I should be running:

```
Total resources:   13
Touched resources: 12
Resource coverage: 92.31%
Untouched resources:
  Class[Nxlog]
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Module and test code would be helpful to even begin appraising your problem. From the output, it would appear that your module managed 13 resources, but your tests account for but 12 of them. At this scale, it might make sense to just take a hard look at the test output, then the code, to see which resource is not yet covered.

Comment: @FelixFrank output and code are both at the link in the post (it goes to a Tavis CI build). The issue is making it see that the module's class itself is being tested. The module us named nxlog and the "untouched resource" is Class[Nxlog]

Answer (score 2):

Remember that *rspec-puppet* does not test the module, per se, rather it tests the compiled catalog.  All you need to do is **indicate that the catalog should contain the class.**  A good place to do this is at the beginning, next to the `comple.with_all_deps` test.

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'my_class' do
  on_supported_os.each do |os,facts|
    context "on #{os}" do
      let(:facts) do
        {
          facts
        }
      end

      context 'without any parameters' do
        it { is_expected.to contain_class('my_class') } # <-- special sauce
        it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }

        it { is_expected.to do_other_things... }
      end
    end
  end
end
```